# Magento 1.9 - Create order using REST API

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api, create-order

I want to create order in magento 1.9 using rest api, but i am unable to find any method to create order using rest api. 
I can't find any help from the below link : **http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html**

Have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as I know it's not possible. Look here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Orders/sales_orders.html

It says:

> HTTP Method: POST /orders
>
> Description: Not implemented.
>
> HTTP Method: PUT /orders
>
> Description: Not implemented.
>
> HTTP Method: DELETE /orders
>
> Description: Not implemented.

You should use [SOAP](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.order.html) instead:

Comment: REST hasn't been completely implemented in Magento 1. So you need to either build it yourself, or use SOAP instead.